# Working with distinct tuples

Tags: tuples, nim-lang

With a type defined as `type BroTuple = distinct tuple[a, b, c: int]`, how can i:

- Create a new instance (`Brotuple()` is telling me `Error: object constructor needs an object type`)
- Access to its fields (`proc example(br: BroTuple) = echo br.a` says: `Error: undeclared field: 'a'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit strange to use a distinct tuple, because the intent of `distinct` is to hide the accessors and procs you would usually have. You should use an object instead if your goal is to prevent ambiguity with other tuples/objects.

If you really want it, here you go:

```
type BroTuple = distinct tuple[a, b, c: int]

var bro = BroTuple((a: 0, b: 0, c: 0))
echo((tuple[a, b, c: int])(bro).a)
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it is strange, but i wanted to know if it was possible.